# How to fetch in C++ at compile time the number of elements in an enum?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, bitmask

Is there a way to fetch the number of elements in an `enum` in C++11 at compile time? In my case the `enum` is a ordered bitmask enum, meaning that first element is `0x0000`, next element is `0x0001` and so on.

Comment: scoped or unscoped enum?

Comment: Often, one just adds an extra member to the enum, named `Count` or something.

Comment: @user463035818 unscoped enum

Comment: the duplicate is not specifically asking for compile time, but the answers apply.